# Matching large datasets of text - how to do it faster?

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, full-text-search, sphinx

I am struggling for weeks now on what would be the best approach to undertake, both logically and technology-wise, while trying to match 2 large sets of text, in a continuous, rotating manner.

On one hand we have songs and their lyrics (around 30M rows of text, with ~1000 chars each), and on the other we have song lyrics categories (around 20K with ~50 chars each). The song lyrics categories are referring to what the songs are about.

Each song should be assigned to one or more categories, and the way I see it, this can only be done by comparing what is the relevance of the words in each of the categories, against the lyrics of the song, followed by picking the one with the biggest full text search score (or more than 1 category, for those that have the same biggest score), taking into account synonyms, stemming, stopwords and all the bells and whistles of a proper full text search engine. If you have better ways of approaching this, please don't hesitate to give me a hint.

As a hypothetical example, according to its lyrics, the song "Unchained Melody" should go to the category:

- Love songs

  - For my darling, my love

    - Feeling lonely

Its lyrics do contain all these words that are contained in the category (its entire path), including inflections and synonyms of them, multiple times, so the text of this category should rank pretty well against the text of the song.

So the question is which possible approach to use for matching all these category texts with all these song texts?

Please keep in mind that, naturally, thousands of songs are released daily nowadays, and the categories are constantly changing/improving even with a chance of radically.

So far I've tried the following:

1. SQL Server 2014 that holds the categories, linking to a Sphinx Search Engine that holds the lyrics texts in its full text index. The app built on top of these performs 20K queries for a single song text (i.e., gets the relevance of each category against the song's text), choosing the result that ranked the best. This means 20K * 30M queries for all the songs to be matched. Of course, this takes ages on a 40 core machine + 256 GB RAM, and by then, there are new songs and possible a changed/updated structure of categories.
2. This one is interesting: SQL Server 2014 that holds the song lyrics, linking to Sphinx that holds the category texts. The query to match a category for each song is created by splitting the song text into words, with "OR" operator between them, the result ranking more if more words are found within a row (containing a category text and the text from its full path). The result: faster, since there's only 1 big query per song to get its top ranked category, but still not fast enough, and slightly less accurate.
3. SQL Server 2014 that holds both the song lyrics and the categories, with Full Text search enabled, while using the first approach (with no Sphinx, just SQL's FT) on a limited set of categories resulted initially from the second approach (again, with no Sphinx, just SQL's FT), and everything split into hundreds of async batches of work. So, it's a combination of the two above. Result: more accurate, and given full power into it, a little more speedy, but still not enough as I feel it would possible. It takes around 3 days to match all songs and lyrics.

If you have any other idea that I could try, I would really appreciate it. I am interested in accuracy (40%) and speed (60%), and I really feel that there are easier ways of doing this job.

Comment: sound likes you are trying to classify a song base on it lyrics. Am I correct?

Comment: It's the closest thing to what I'm really trying to do, which is actually far more complicated. But yes, it can safely be considered as a correct assumption.

Comment: I'm not answering you question, just trying to discuss and give you some suggestions. Because, you are facing a big problem and you should specify how good you can be. I see you did not mention your preprocessing. Did you reduce the complexity of the documents in simpler structure?

Comment: I can't see which pre-processing would be useful for me to do. I only did little things: eliminating any non alphanumeric char (all punctuation), except spaces from all the texts, I tried keeping IO to a minimum by archiving all the texts in plain tables stored on a RAM drive, so that there is not a single join, or any operation other than pure data reading from a single & simple location that takes place during matching operations.

Comment: Many search engines do not save full text to DB. They will convert document to simpler structure. It will help you in reducing workload. They are many way to present a document. VPM (vector space model) is one of them. I suggest you read Taming Text by Grant S.Ingersoll. It is top-down explanation, easy to understand.

Comment: Sorry. It is VSM, not VPM ^^

Comment: Indeed, Sphinx does not store the texts at all. The queries to Sphinx only return the entry IDs and it's averaging less than 0.05s per query. SQL's FTS is similar in speed on that machine. So I am not really worried about the storage and its performance, but more on the approach, because no matter how good a query will do, it's still 30M * 20K queries to do in a loop.

Comment: Did you try classify the input, what are suitable categories?

Comment: You mean to prefilter the categories before selecting one of them as the winner? Yes, that would be point 3 of my approaches.

Comment: how do you choose potential categories?

Comment: It's approach no.3: Select Top 10 From approach no.2, giving back 10 best ranked categories, and then approach no.1 only with those category texts, performing queries counting a total 10*number_of_songs, instead of 20K*number_of_songs per loop.

Comment: here is my last try in helping ^^, read this: http://thinknook.com/10-ways-to-improve-your-classification-algorithm-performance-2013-01-21/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would probably stick with your 1. but with two refinements

**Batch Updates**, rather simply run one query for every category/document combination. Run one query per category - and get results for ALL the documents. Fewer bigger queries. There are optimizations you can do to make these 'big' queries rather efficient.

**Delta Updates**, rather than every period, just running the 'full' process, use a separate smaller and specific system periodically. One that knows how to run more focused updates to avoid repeating work. For example:

1. Of you add a new category, can just run its big query to find the documents for that category. A removed category just deltes the records. A 'edit' to a category, can be a delete followed by a insert.
2. New documents, could also be a special sphinx index that ONLY contains the new documents (a main+delta indexing system might already provide that!). Then run the main query for every category against this much smaller delta index.
3. possibly could even use a 'speculative' system to cut down the number of categories you need to run. eg, bung all the words from categories into bulk BuildKeyword calls. This gets you back hits per word, with this you can rule out categories that have NO matches (so no need to run the main query, for many categories)

... work smarter, not harder